# How to retry 5 times with intervals of 1, 5, 10, 30, 60 seconds using Spring Retry in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry, retrypolicy

For example, the method was called at 12:00:00 but failed.

I like it to retry at 12:00:01, 12:00:06, 12:00:16, 12:00:46, 12:01:46

How could I make it happen using Spring Retry in Java

I tried the following Custom BackOff Policy but it shows error:

```
    @Autowired
    private BackOffPolicy customBackOffPolicy;

    @Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttempts = 6, backoff = @Backoff(customBackOffPolicy))
    public ResponseResult<List<String>> get() {
        System.out.println("start: " + LocalTime.now());
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
        System.out.println("done");
        return ResponseResult.success(list);
    }
```

[image: error message]

Comment: With what you show here the value is a constant. Please show the actual code and actual error.

Comment: Update your question to show the actual (relevant) code, then vote to reopen.

Comment: It's called Exponential Backoff and you can configure it with the [intervalWithCustomExponentialBackoff](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry#use-a-custom-intervalfunction).